# How to build a 64 bit native JNI library on AIX

Tags: java-native-interface, g++, 64-bit, aix, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am trying to compile and build 64 bit native library on AIX system and execute using JNI Java. My library contains a simple C++ program which accepts a string and returns reversing it. Basically, I created it in 32 bit environment first, it executed absolutely fine. Here are my commands:

**32bit:**

```
g++ -Wall -I/usr/java14/include -shared Reverse.cpp -o libReverse.so
```

The library generated also looks 32 bit environment specific

```
$ file libReverse.so
libReverse.so: executable (RISC System/6000) or object module not stripped
```

and I execute it using 32bit Java which works fine

```
 $  /usr/java14/bin/java -Djava.library.path=. com/test/Reverse test
 tset
```

But when I try the same thing for 64 bit, problem occurs. First I recompile the java class using 64 bit JVM (we have 32 bit and 64 bit installed in same machine) and generate the library 64 bit

```
$ java -d64 -version
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pap6470sr4fp2-20130426_01(SR4 FP2))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.6, JRE 1.7.0 AIX ppc64-64 Compressed References 20130422_146026 (JIT     enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R26_Java726_SR4_FP2_20130422_1320_B146026
JIT  - r11.b03_20130131_32403ifx4
GC   - R26_Java726_SR4_FP2_20130422_1320_B146026_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20130422_146026)
JCL - 20130425_01 based on Oracle 7u21-b09
```

Here is the compile options I used:

```
$ g++ -maix64 -Wall -I/usr/java7_64/include/ -I/usr/java7_64/include/aix/ -shared Reverse.cpp -o libReverse.so
$ file libReverse.so
libReverse.so: 64-bit XCOFF executable or object module not stripped
```

This is the output I get

```
 $ java -Djava.library.path=. com/test/Reverse test
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Reverse (A file or  directory in the path name does not exist.)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1197)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1161)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:527)
    at com.test.Reverse.<clinit>(Reverse.java:9)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:236)
```

This is my G++ version details:

```
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0
Configured with: ../configure --with-as=/usr/bin/as --with-ld=/usr/bin/ld --enable-    languages=c,c++,java --prefix=/opt/freeware --enable-threads --enable-version-specific-    runtime-libs --host=powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0 --target=powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0 --build=powerpc-    ibm-aix6.1.0.0 --disable-libjava-multilib
Thread model: aix
gcc version 4.2.0
```

While executing the java, I had them in my PATH/LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

1. My doubts are: Am I not able to generate the 64 bit library properly?Is
   there any options got missed out while linking/compiling in G++? I
   added **-maix64** got it from internet.
2. Is G++ has platform specific
   installation? or same installation I can use for both 32bit/64bit by
   passing options?
3. If yes, how do I check current installation supporting 32 bit/64 bit?

**Can you please share the command to build the same in 64 bit?**

Help Appreciated! Let me know if you need any other information.
Regards,
Bhaskar

**----------------------Modifications I did after suggestions ------------------**

**64 bit**

Export an environment variable OBJECT_MODE=64 to facilitate the 64 bit compile and link environment

```
$ export  OBJECT_MODE=64
```

Recompiled the java class using 64 bit java

```
javac -d64 -d classes/ com/test/Reverse.java
```

Generate the header file using 64 bit java

```
javah -d64 -jni com.test.Reverse
```

Compile and generate the library

```
g++ -maix64 -Wall -I/usr/java7_64/include/ -I/usr/java7_64/include/aix/ -shared Reverse.cpp -o libReverse.so
```

After quering symbols it looks like:

```
$ nm -g libReverse.so
.Java_com_test_Reverse_reverse T   268436588
._GLOBAL__DD         T   268437816
._GLOBAL__DI         T   268437740
._GLOBAL__FD_libReverse_so T   268437532
._GLOBAL__FI_libReverse_so T   268437324
._ZN7JNIEnv_12NewStringUTFEPKc T   268436080
._ZN7JNIEnv_17GetStringUTFCharsEP8_jstringPh T   268436408
._ZN7JNIEnv_18GetStringUTFLengthEP8_jstring T   268436236
.__deregister_frame_info T   268437116
.__fd_select         T   268436040
.__register_frame_info_table T   268437076
.malloc              T   268436000
.strlen              T   268435960
Java_com_test_Reverse_reverse D   536873888
_GLOBAL__FD_libReverse_so D   536873984
_GLOBAL__FI_libReverse_so D   536873912
_GLOBAL__F_Java_com_test_Reverse_reverse_298BA8FC D   536873352
_ZN7JNIEnv_12NewStringUTFEPKc D   536873816          24
_ZN7JNIEnv_17GetStringUTFCharsEP8_jstringPh D   536873864          24
_ZN7JNIEnv_18GetStringUTFLengthEP8_jstring D   536873840          24
__deregister_frame_info U           -
__fd_select          U           -
__gxx_personality_v0 U           -
__register_frame_info_table U           -
malloc               U           -
strlen               U           -
$ file libReverse.so
libReverse.so: 64-bit XCOFF executable or object module not stripped
```

When I run with -d64 option

```
$ java -d64 -Djava.library.path=. com/test/Reverse test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Reverse (A file or directory     in the path name does not exist.)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1197)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1161)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:527)
    at com.test.Reverse.<clinit>(Reverse.java:9)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:236)
```

Trying to use **-m64** option instead of **-maix64**

```
$ g++ -m64 -Wall -I/usr/java7_64/include/ -I/usr/java7_64/include/aix/ -shared     Reverse.cpp -o libReverse.so
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-m64"
```

Still no luck and I am stuck at **UnsatisfiedLinkError**, Is there anything I am still missing?

Comment: Have you tried -m64 instead of -maix64? Have you tried `java -d64 -Djava.library.path=. com/test/Reverse test`?  What is the output of `nm -g libReverse.so` on the 64bit lib?

Comment: Make sure you invoke java with `-d64`, you omitted that from your description of trying to run 64-bit.

Comment: @AlexBarker @technomanage (1). I tried the `-d64` option, it throws the same UnsatisfiedLinkerror                                         (2). `nm -g` option in the 64 bit library shows                            `nm -g libReverse.so
0654-210 libReverse.so is not valid in the current object file mode.
        Use the -X option to specify the desired object mode` I think there is some problem lying in. (3). When I use `-m64` instead of `-maix64` it shows `cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-m64"` , Could you please suggest further? Thanks Bhaskar

Comment: Is there anything related with G++ installation? like it can't generate 64 bit libraries if it is 32 bit installation. I don't see any option for checking bit option in G++ like java. Thanks

Comment: @AlexBarker, I fixed this `nm -g` output `libReverse.so is not valid in the current object file mode` by setting an environment variable `OBJECT_MODE=64`, but still the problem persists. I have recompiled the libraries and generated the header files also with `-d64`, but no luck. I modified the  original post what I did. Your suggestion highly appreciated! Bhaskar

Comment: What does `ldd libReverse.so` say? Or `dump -X64 -H libReverse.so`?